# java.lang.NullPointerException:Parameter specified as non null is null: method WeatherEntityMapper.mapWeatherEntityToWeatherData

Tags: android, kotlin, openweathermap

The issue occurs in my mapper class `mapWeatherEntityToWeatherData`,where I made `weatherEntity` an instance of `WeatherEntity` none of the values are null even from the API:

```
object WeatherEntityMapper {
    fun mapWeatherEntityToWeatherData(weatherEntity: WeatherEntity): WeatherData {
        Log.d("entity null", weatherEntity.toString())
        val currentWeather = Weather(
            sunrise = weatherEntity.sunrise,
            sunset = weatherEntity.sunset,
            temperature = weatherEntity.temperature,
            feelsLike = weatherEntity.feelsLike,
            pressure = weatherEntity.pressure,
            humidity = weatherEntity.humidity,
            visibility = weatherEntity.visibility,
            uvi = weatherEntity.uvi,
            windSpeed = weatherEntity.windSpeed,
            windDegree = weatherEntity.windDegree,
            weather = weatherEntity.weather,
        )

        return WeatherData(
            background = getBackgroundFromId(weatherEntity.background),
            current = currentWeather,
            forecasts = convertJsonToList(weatherEntity.forecasts)?: emptyList()
        )
    }

    fun mapWeatherDataToWeatherEntity(weatherData: WeatherData): WeatherEntity {
        val currentWeather = weatherData.current

        return WeatherEntity(
            background = getIdFromBackground(weatherData.background),
            sunrise = currentWeather.sunrise,
            sunset = currentWeather.sunset,
            temperature = currentWeather.temperature,
            feelsLike = currentWeather.feelsLike,
            pressure = currentWeather.pressure,
            humidity = currentWeather.humidity,
            visibility = currentWeather.visibility,
            uvi = currentWeather.uvi,
            windSpeed = currentWeather.windSpeed,
            windDegree = currentWeather.windDegree,
            weather = currentWeather.weather,
            forecasts = convertListToJson(weatherData.forecasts)

        )

    }

    @DrawableRes
    private fun getBackgroundFromId(id: Int): Int {
        return when (id) {
            0 -> R.drawable.bg_morning
            1 -> R.drawable.bg_day
            2 -> R.drawable.bg_evening
            else -> R.drawable.bg_night
        }
    }

    private fun getIdFromBackground(@DrawableRes id: Int): Int {
        return when (id) {
            R.drawable.bg_morning -> 0
            R.drawable.bg_day -> 1
            R.drawable.bg_evening -> 2
            else -> 3
        }
    }

    private fun convertListToJson(forecasts: List<DailyForecast>): String {
        val jsonList = forecasts.map { forecast ->
            forecast.copy(icon = getIdFromIcon(forecast.icon))
        }
        return Gson().toJson(jsonList)
    }

    private fun convertJsonToList(forecasts: String): List<DailyForecast> {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<DailyForecast>>() {}.type
        val jsonList: List<DailyForecast> = Gson().fromJson(forecasts, type)
        return jsonList.map { forecast ->
            forecast.copy(icon = getIconFromId(forecast.icon))
        }
    }

    @DrawableRes
    private fun getIconFromId(id: Int): Int {
        return when (id) {
            0 -> R.drawable.ic_clear_day
            1 -> R.drawable.ic_cloudy_day
            2 -> R.drawable.ic_rain
            3 -> R.drawable.ic_thunderstorm
            4 -> R.drawable.ic_snow
            5 -> R.drawable.ic_fog
            else -> R.drawable.ic_tornado
        }
    }

    private fun getIdFromIcon(@DrawableRes id: Int): Int {
        return when (id) {
            R.drawable.ic_clear_day -> 0
            R.drawable.ic_cloudy_day -> 1
            R.drawable.ic_rain -> 2
            R.drawable.ic_thunderstorm -> 3
            R.drawable.ic_snow -> 4
            R.drawable.ic_fog -> 5
            else -> 6
        }
    }
}
```

This is the weather entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "weather_data")
data class WeatherEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id:Int = 1,
    val background:Int,
    val sunrise:String,
    val sunset:String,
    val temperature:Double,
    val feelsLike:Double,
    val pressure:Int,
    val humidity:Int,
    val visibility:Int,
    val uvi:Double,
    val windSpeed:Double,
    val windDegree:Int,
    val weather:String,
    val forecasts:String
)
```

I have tried logging but I can pinpoint the exactly variable causing the null pointer exception where the null value originates.

This is the weather response from the API should it be needed

```
data class WeatherResponse(
    val lat: Double,
    val lon: Double,
    val timezone: String,
    @SerializedName("timezone_offset")
    val timezoneOffset: Int,
    val current: CurrentWeather,
    val daily: List<DailyWeather>,
    val hourly: List<HourlyWeather>
)
//these are the data contained in the data classes

data class CurrentWeather(
    val dt: Long,
    val temp: Double,
    val sunrise: Long,
    val sunset: Long,
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    val feelsLike: Double,
    val pressure: Int,
    val humidity: Int,
    val dewPoint: Double,
    val uvi: Double,
    val clouds: Int,
    val visibility: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    val windSpeed: Double,
    @SerializedName("wind_deg")
    val windDeg: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_gust")
    val windGust: Double,
    val weather: List<Weather>,
)


data class DailyWeather(
    val dt: Long,
    val temp: Temp,
    val sunrise: Long,
    val sunset: Long,
    val moonrise: Long,
    val moonSet: Long,
    val moonPhase: Double,
    val summary: String,
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    val feelsLike: FeelsLike,
    val pressure: Int,
    val humidity: Int,
    @SerializedName("dew_point")
    val dewPoint: Double,
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    val windSpeed: Double,
    @SerializedName("wind_deg")
    val windDeg: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_gust")
    val windGust: Double,
    val clouds: Int,
    val pop: Double,
    val uvi: Double,
    val weather: List<Weather>,
)


data class HourlyWeather(
    val dt: Long,
    val temp: Temp,
    val weather: List<Weather>,
    val pressure: Int,
    val humidity: Int,
    val dewPoint: Double,
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    val feelsLike: FeelsLike,
    val uvi: Double,
    val clouds: Int,
    val visibility: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    val windSpeed: Double,
    @SerialName("wind_deg")
    val windDeg: Int,
    @SerialName("wind_gust")
    val windGust: Double,
)


data class Temp(
    val day: Double,
    val min: Double,
    val max: Double,
    val night: Double,
    val eve: Double,
    val morn: Double
)


data class FeelsLike(
    val day: Double,
    val night: Double,
    val eve: Double,
    val morn: Double
)

data class Weather(
    val id: Int,
    val main: String,
    val description: String,
    val icon: String
)
```

Comment: `none of the values are null even from the API:` well clearly the exception disagrees with you :) time for a debugger, step over and check all the values, not much we can do for you here really. perhaps start with a response that only has 2 variables, then you add another 2, till you find where the error is coming from